How to run vite on hostinger?
I recently uploaded my laravel project on hostinger. Everything works fine apart from the vite. How to configure it to use npm and vite?
When I open the project I got this error:

Internal Server Error
Illuminate\Foundation\ViteManifestNotFoundException
Vite manifest not found at: /home/u677060802/domains/lara11.balazskelemen.co.uk/public/build/manifest.json

I was trying to run the backend laravel breeze and front end vite

If you are using shared-hosting you can't use node. You should build your project first and then deploy to your hosting.
